# SwiftUI Charts - Plotting Hours and Minutes on the y axis

Tags: swiftui, charts

I'm plotting sunrise - date against time, and it works but not perfectly.
How do I plot Hours and Minutes on the y axis, as a compound time.
If I just plots hours I get a step chart:

[image]

```
     Chart{
            ForEach(sunriseSunset) {item in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("Date", item.sunrise),
                    y: .value("Time", (Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: item.sunrise).hour!))       
                )
            }
        }
```

Alternatively if I multiple the hours * 60 and add the minutes I get the correct curve but the intervals on the RHS are in minutes. Is there a way to express the time as hours/minutes?

[image]

```
    Chart{
        ForEach(sunriseSunset) {item in
            LineMark(
                x: .value("Date", item.sunrise),       
                y: .value("Time", ((Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: item.sunrise).hour!) * 60) + (Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: item.sunrise).minute!))
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: try using the Double, time since 1970 variable but you likely need to create more plot points, maybe add a stride

Comment: Apologies - not been able to make any progress with that or find any examples.

Comment: I think this would be very specific to your code, I doubt there would be a tutorial or sample code out there.

Comment: Can you please post the code for the sunriseSunset array? I am having trouble coming up with a dataSet for that...